# Using signal strength feature of nRF24L01 module

Tags: arduino-uno, nrf24l01+

This is a walkie-talkie project and this circuit really worked, voice can be transmitted from one nRF module to another nRF. Additionally, I want to observe how well the signal strength is, by lighting up an LED.

[image]

They talked about a test.RPD function [here](https://forum.mysensors.org/topic/1022/nrf24l01-signal-strength-request/6) in order to do that. But it is said that we can't use this with nRF24L01, but can use only with nRF24L01P (I don't know what is the difference).

> Test whether a signal (carrier or otherwise) greater than
>   or equal to -64dBm is present on the channel. Valid only
>   on ***nRF24L01P*** (+) hardware. On ***nRF24L01***, use testCarrier().
>   Useful to check for interference on the current channel and
>   channel hopping strategies.
>   @return true if signal => -64dBm, false if not
>   */

---

***Can't we use it in nRF24L01 really?***

If I cannot use this how can I use the `testCarrier` function to light up an LED (as Bright, Low and Off) as mentioned in the quote?

If I can use this, what changes in the code should be done? (The member TmrhProjects talked about it a little)

---

He also hints to this code.

```
bool rpd = radio.testRPD();

while (radio.available()) {
  signalStrength = rpd + 1;
  radio.read, etc...
}
```

**Should we write the above code in the `RF24.h` file or should we write it directly into the Arduino's main sketch?**

Answer (score 1):

To get the signal strength just send 100 packets with no retries and see how many times the packet arrives.

```
radio.begin();             
radio.setRetries(0,0); // by default nrf tries 15 times. Change to no retries to measure strength

char buffer[32];
int counter = 0;

for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
   int status = radio.send(buffer,32); // send 32 bytes of data. It does not matter what it is
   if(status)
       counter++;

   delay(1); // try again in 1 millisecond
}

// if counter > 80 signal strength is great
{

}

// else if counter > 60 signal strength is good
{

}

// etc

radio.setRetries(5,15); change back to its default when done.
```

For this code to work the receiver must be listening for data. Just listen for data on the receiver there is no need to validate the data.